# Conditionally call closure in case of error in result chain

Tags: rust

I have a long chain of `Result()` returning functions, which are chained using `and_then` and similar functions. I would like to print an error in case any of the function fail, without using the returned value. I need a sort of `if_err` function, which can be chained to a result, and call a closure in case of an `Error`:

```rust
foo()
    .and_then(|x| bar1(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar2(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar3(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar4(x))
    .if_err(|err| { println!("Error: {}", err); });
```

These are the existing patterns available in the language:

```rust
foo()
    .and_then(|x| bar1(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar2(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar3(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar4(x))
    .unwrap_or_else(|err| { println!("Error: {}", err); });
```

and:

```rust
if let Error(err) = foo()
        .and_then(|x| bar1(x))
        .and_then(|x| bar2(x))
        .and_then(|x| bar3(x))
        .and_then(|x| bar4(x)) {
    println!("Error: {}", err); });
}
```

Is there anything better than this?

Comment: [ok_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) ?

Comment: @heemayl on a `Result`?

Comment: [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)?

Answer (score 3):

On nightly, you can use [`Result::inspect_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err):

```rust
foo()
    .and_then(|x| bar1(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar2(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar3(x))
    .and_then(|x| bar4(x))
    .inspect_err(|err| { println!("Error: {}", err); });
```

If you're on stable, you can polyfill it quite easily:

```rust
pub trait ResultExt<T, E> {
    fn inspect<F: FnOnce(&T)>(self, f: F) -> Self;
    fn inspect_err<F: FnOnce(&E)>(self, f: F) -> Self;
}
impl<T, E> ResultExt<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn inspect<F: FnOnce(&T)>(self, f: F) -> Self {
        if let Ok(ref v) = self { f(v); }
        self
    }
    fn inspect_err<F: FnOnce(&E)>(self, f: F) -> Self {
        if let Err(ref v) = self { f(v); }
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed `inspect_err` is exactly what I was looking for! I felt that such function is missing and this is the reason I asked this question in the first place. Nice to see that the language is evolving so fast.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a matter of opinion, but I would go one of two ways. The first option is definitely my preference, because it makes it clear we don't care about the result. The second is just a way of "cleaning up" the method chain so the closure braces aren't necessary.

#### Option 1 ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc1d306140b7605f7ea850af4523b1ef)):

```
let result = foo()
    .and_then(bar1)
    .and_then(bar2)
    .and_then(bar3)
    .and_then(bar4);

if let Err(err) = result {
    println!("Error: {}", err);
}
```

#### Option 2 ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2137483f4d93559b5a87ea566e7028f)):

```
foo()
    .and_then(bar1)
    .and_then(bar2)
    .and_then(bar3)
    .and_then(bar4)
    .err()
    .map(|err| println!("Error: {}", err));
```

---

As an aside, I personally think `Result` and `Option` could do with some kind of `peek()` method (like the method of the same name in [Java's stream API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api)), but for now we have to make do without.

ETA: It looks like this feature slipped into the language while I wasn't looking! Thanks to Chayim for bringing it to my attention in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871528/1813169).

Comment: In option 1, storing `result` in a variable kind of breaks the flow. I was looking for a function that will be part of the chain, and your `.err().map(|err| ...)` is a rather good alternative. However, the best answer TMHO is @Chayim's `inspect_err`.